# I can't download needed assets and dependencies using $ rake bower:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

my environments are follows
    os.   :   mac
    rails : 5.0.5
    rvm  :  ruby-2.4.0
    node  :  v6.11.2
    npm.  :   5.3.0
To download needed assets I run the following command on terminal.
    $ rake bower:install
and i got follow errors.

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007feb54ef8b38>
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
/Users/admin/workspace/now/angular_example/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
/Users/admin/workspace/now/angular_example/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:AngularExample>'
/Users/admin/workspace/now/angular_example/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/workspace/now/angular_example/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/admin/workspace/now/angular_example/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 4.1.4, and maybe some other versions after 4.0.8, the first line in those files is generated as `Rails.application.configure.do` rather than, using a project called sample_app as an example, `SampleApp::Application.configure.do` as in 4.0.8.

Comment: I want to know the way to fix this bug and download needed assets.
And I can't understand how this answer could solve my error.

Comment: change your config/application.rb with SampleApp::Application.configure. after that update bundle.